# Var cannot be found

Tags: javascript, ios, touch, var

I have a little problem with following code, it throws a error saying that the vars `startPos` and `refresh` cannot be found.

```
var listElem = document.getElementById('list');
listElem.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
    var startPos = $("#content").scrollTop(),
    eraInput = document.getElementById('input'),
    refresh = false;
});
listElem.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
    if (refresh) {
        if (!$("#input").is(":focus")) {
            $("#input").val("");
        }
        // Stuff...
    }
});
listElem.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    var move_to = startPos-(e.touches[0].clientY-e.changedTouches[0].screenY);
    if (move_to > 50) {
        refresh = true;
    } else {
        refresh = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: You really need to read up on "scope" in javascript. Decent article: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/

Comment: Start your code by defining those two variables, so that they will be present.

Comment: You never initialize the refresh variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every function definition creates its own scope in JavaScript. That means you can't declare a variable inside a function an use it inside another function. When you need shared variables, they need to be declared on a common scope:

```
var listElem = document.getElementById('list'),
    startPos,
    refresh,
    eraInput;
listElem.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
    startPos = $("#content").scrollTop(),
    eraInput = document.getElementById('input'),
    refresh = false;
});
listElem.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
    if (refresh) {
        if (!$("#input").is(":focus")) {
            $("#input").val("");
        }
        // Stuff...
    }
});
listElem.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    var move_to = startPos-(e.touches[0].clientY-e.changedTouches[0].screenY);
    if (move_to > 50) {
        refresh = true;
    } else {
        refresh = false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should specify them outside the `eventListener`:

```
var startPos, eraInput, refresh;

var listElem = document.getElementById('list');
listElem.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
    startPos = $("#content").scrollTop();
    eraInput = document.getElementById('input');
    refresh = false;
});
listElem.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
    if (refresh) {
        if (!$("#input").is(":focus")) {
            $("#input").val("");
        }
        // Stuff...
    }
});
listElem.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    var move_to = startPos-(e.touches[0].clientY-e.changedTouches[0].screenY);
    if (move_to > 50) {
        refresh = true;
    } else {
        refresh = false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var listElem = document.getElementById('list');
var startPos;
var refresh;
listElem.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
    startPos = $("#content").scrollTop(),
    eraInput = document.getElementById('input'),
    refresh = false;
});
listElem.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
    if (refresh) {
        if (!$("#input").is(":focus")) {
            $("#input").val("");
        }
        // Stuff...
    }
});
listElem.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    var move_to = startPos-(e.touches[0].clientY-e.changedTouches[0].screenY);
    if (move_to > 50) {
        refresh = true;
    } else {
        refresh = false;
    }
});​
```

Comment: Forgot the `;` in the first part.

Answer (score 0):

Your variables look to be out of the scope you're accessing them.

Declare the variables right after listElem and have them set in the 'touchstart' event.